# Unity Script can not reach Game Manager after loading a new scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If i load a new scene in my project, i get "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" error about my Game Manager. For example, this error occures in another script reaching "GameManager.instance.LevelStarted" and another variables from GameManager.instance.

But i set up my Game Manager with instance like this in my GameManager.cs script:

```
public static GameManager instance;

    void MakeSingleton()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
         MakeSingleton();
    }
```

I load a new scene in my Game Manager like this:

```
    public void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong? What should i do my scripts to reach GameManager variables after loading new scene?

Comment: I tested your script in a new unity project and it seems to be working fine, I can access the `GameManager .Instance` even after loading a new scene. Maybe add on `OnDestroy` function to the `GameManager` and and use breakpoints to find where its getting destroyed?

Comment: I added `OnDestroy` function with a `Debug.Log` message in it and my GameManager destroys itself when new scene is loaded. Does it mean that `DontDestroyOnLoad` function does not working?

Comment: Chances are it’s destroying a second copy. Not the first. You dont show how you’ve referenced it in your code but unless you specifically call to destroy it somewhere else this should remain

Comment: It was the second copy that is being destroyed like you said. I made mistakes in another scripts when i reference variables from GameManager. After i corrected it, it started to work. Question is solved.